# Infer type for the interface field from the return type of another field

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I would like to have a types for defining configuration for sorting. These are the types I have described:

```
export type SortConfig<T> = ReadonlyArray<SortItemConfig<T>>;
export interface SortItemConfig<T> {
  field: (obj: T) => any;
  direction: SortDirection;
  compareFn?: SortFn<any>;
}

export const SORT_DIRECTIONS = {
  ASC: 'asc',
  DESC: 'desc',
} as const;


export type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
export type SortDirection = ValueOf<typeof SORT_DIRECTIONS>;
export type SortFn<T> = (a: T, b: T) => number;
```

The aim is to have the return type of `SortItemConfig.field` to be the same as input type for `SortItemConfig.compareFn`. Is it possible? Here is an example:

```
interface Player {
  name: string;
  character: 'human' | 'alien';
  rank: number;
  stats: PlayerStats;
}

interface PlayerStats {
  wins: number;
  loses: number;
  totalMatches: number;
  notes?: string;
}


const sortConfig: SortConfig<Player> = [
  {
    field: (player) => player.rank,
    direction: SORT_DIRECTIONS.ASC,
    // I want rank1 and rank2 to be the same type as the return type of "field" - typeof player.rank. Is this possible?
    compareFn: (rank1, rank2) => {
      return rank1 - rank2;
    }
  },
  {
    field: (player) => player.stats,
    direction: SORT_DIRECTIONS.ASC,
    // Same here, stat1 and stat2 should be infered as PlayerStats type
    compareFn: (stat1, stat2) => {
      return stat1.wins - stat2.wins;
    }
  }
];
```

I've tried to introduce a new generic for the type, but this doesn't help:

```
export type SortConfig<T> = ReadonlyArray<SortItemConfig<T, any>>;
export interface SortItemConfig<T, R> {
  field: (obj: T) => R;
  direction: SortDirection;
  compareFn?: SortFn<R>;
}
```

Here's a link to a playground with all described types and an example of using these types:

[TS Playgorund link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=52&ssc=3&pln=20&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDK0YGEIDsBmAlgOYA8AKgHxwC8cASsAIYAmeANogIJRROKkMsAJIxgAWxwESFSpQDcAKFCRYcQrjFR8TAMaohMURKlEyVOAG9FcOEWDsWALjgAKCACMAVi-IBKWmomXEQlWxZCKGBdGEI8F0MAEUjo2LwwuF0IcTAmKIAxXAB%20BMxC0mDEBUUAX0VlcExMvABneDQAeXpyAH1E4XoAUSxyYQ6AOTRaKxs4LjQsFwByJhbdJYAaWcTBheWWYDXN2rhV5tw2pXqVJqQUOAA1JnYAV2AO-Flp8gBtAGtgIgIPg4OQALpKG5qO4GTDJKIxOK4aZPV7vT4w4HoLq9fpDEZjSbVKHwGHoMq4L50VxMXwbOAeXwBGjUXAvcQeYBQK4Aeh5tBogqFwpForF4olkqF9Q0Wh0%20jgAAV2PwuTNbLgmOJgC42lANMQMroABZ5PRaZbG9nBJZwAA%20cBW7EIwFwSwyfFwfxcbI5XIybSYMBaLmVqqgaBgQZaSjqillXPlqDDiC5kej6rgAHcNCG4L7OdzZuwIC1Dj72YWMjAIFH2ABZIMm8v5yv%202a4WuHEpwPUG2P1RRZC7wFqYUwkUqwCdkFNc6h0H6zay2Wz2RwuVxgFWpqDM6jb8MAOk9fy2q7gEQRaVwCRxfQGw1GEzQR-mWHPq75cGE2eCpIgOBTwARlOXAWCA4I-gAJgZVAYGNVAWi1eDkFQM4ENQKIYBeKBkTJLEACJ1xYQi4AAWgQNCsUPXcTygo8fxaBBjUIZjIBaFpCA8dhgCKWZbCyHI8mAQpNxA%20lT2g-dMwvbDcORECKMgr1oIyWw6g0z8V1XEjN1orkZIMqAj0DYNP3CFJEXibFugffFn0mN8FgsuBvzQFC4EQqJ6TM0DgggszYJaY0IBeRw4PUAguWACCayVHc0yjYMBOaYSClvNw-N85LpMCWTV3kvDe2S4CjxzC5lKC8rc3UuBNPqxQISAA)

Appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

---

**UPD.** Here is how I use `SortConfig<T>` in the code. There is a `Sorting<T>` class which provides a `sortFn` for the type `T` based on the configuration:

```
export class Sorting<T> {
  private readonly sortConfig: SortConfig<T>;

  constructor(sortConfig: SortConfig<T>) {
    this.sortConfig = sortConfig;
  }

  public getSortFn() {
    return (objA: T, objB: T): number => {
      for (const sort of this.sortConfig) {
        const compare = this.getCompareFn(sort);

        let result = compare(sort.field(objA), sort.field(objB));
        result = isAscending(sort.direction) ? result : -result;

        if (result !== 0) {
          return result;
        }
      }

      return 0;
    };
  }

  protected getCompareFn(sort: SortItemConfig<T>): SortFn<any> {
    return sort.compareFn ?? compareValues;
  }
}

function isAscending(sortDirection: SortDirection): boolean {
  return sortDirection === SORT_DIRECTIONS.ASC;
}

function compareValues(a: unknown, b: unknown): number {
  // Stubbed implementation
  return -1;
}
```

The intention is to be able to see the infered types during the declaration of the variable `const sortConfig: SortConfig<T>` as an array of `SortItemConfig<T>` for different field types, like it was described in the example.

Comment: You need to introduce another generic type parameter like `R` if you want to track that information.  You say "this doesn't help" presumably because you don't get the *inference* you want, and yes, such things are currently beyond TS's ability to infer (it's one of the outstanding cases described at [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599)). You can either just manually annotate types that are not inferred, or look at writing a bunch of workaround helper functions. What do you intend to *do* with a `SortConfig<T>`? That will drive the solution.

Comment: ... for example, you could encode `SortConfig` as an array of *existentially quantified generic types* as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQqRAw), but whether that helps or hurts you depends strongly on your use case.   Did I guess correctly what you're trying to do?  If so I'll write up my answer. If not, please [edit] to clarify the use case.

Comment: @jcalz the post has been just updated. Basically the types in your example is exactly what I'm trying to achive. I need some time to try your solution and see if I can apply it to the class I've described in the update. Hopefully I'll done this tomorrow

Comment: With your update my code looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDV8zW) (note how `compareValues` is not defined, perhaps instead of describing it with words you could just [edit] to supply the actual function, which is probably shorter and clearer).  But yeah it's not much different from what I showed.  Let me know when you get a chance to review so I can proceed.

Comment: @jcalz your code works as I expect, thanks! Could you please explain more about the `SomeSortItemConfig<T>` and the helper function `someSortItemConfig`? I actually don't understand what the `return cb => cb(sic)` means and how it works. Do you have any links describing this TS techinque?

Comment: See the linked q/a.  You're looking for a *heterogeneous array* and the approach with existentially quantified generics is described there.